# New (+) button in subgrid defaults to add existing instead of create new

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a subgrid for an `entity`,

I want to remove the suggestions that comes when I try to add new  `entity items` to it
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you saying that right now when you click the + button, the default behavior is to search for an existing record but you want the default behavior to be adding a new record?

Comment: yeah right, I want to create new record whenever a record needs to be added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the subgrid is a 1:N relationship, edit the properties of the lookup attribute on the child entity to make it required.

> In the case of 1:N relationships, if the lookup attribute on the child
>   entity is a required attribute the Add button will act as the 'Add
>   New...' button. Otherwise, it acts as the 'Add Existing... button.

See [here](https://community.adxstudio.com/blogs/developer/2014-01-29-understanding-the-add-button-on-sub-grids/) and [here](http://crmtipoftheday.com/2013/11/11/make-a-subgrid-button-launch-a-new-record-form/) for more info (there are many more articles about this issue you can find).

Comment: thanks @Polshgiant, can you suggest a good place to learn CRM ?

Comment: It's mostly just a long-term accumulation of knowledge from the SDK, coworkers, and Google.  The "How do I", "Connect to", "Extend" pages from the [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453.aspx) (see left) are where I recommend anyone new would start.  Tons of good info.  Plus all of the code samples in the SDK.  Also, follow some [blogs](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/p/allblogs) and you'll learn a lot too. If there are courses in your area or online, that would be a good jump start.

Comment: excellent, that would hep a lot to get started
Thanks @Polshgiant